# How to build .IPA file for testing in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo, ipa

I have build a project in react-native, for now I am testing the android app by using Expo Client App. I am using Visual Code in Ubuntu 18.04. 
So the problem is, now I want to test the project for IOS, but unfortunately i can't test the app, because I don't have MAC OS. 
Can anyone tell me the alternative solution of testing react-native project on IOS?
And if somehow there is a solution of creating IPA,then can I use that IPA in IOS without uploading it in AppStore?

Answer (score -1):

You can use snack :

> Snack lets you  run complete react native project in a web browser,you can set it up on your local machine directly use it from [snack.io](https://snack.expo.io/) which also let's you test for android and ios as well

[image: running react native project in web browser]

Comment: there are many dependencies issues. Can you kindly tell me how to resolve them? i even replaced my `package.json` file with the default one. but still its not picking up those dependencies.

Comment: please attach a screenshot of the errors stacktrace